# What‘s the difference between srand(1) and srand(0)

Tags: c++, c, random, srand

I just found out the hard way that `srand(1)` resets the PRNG of C(++) to the state before any call to `srand` (as defined in the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/)).
However, the seed 0 seems to do the same, or the state before any call to `srand` seems to use the seed 0.
What’s the difference between those two calls or what is the reason they do the same thing?

For example this code ([execute on Ideone](http://ideone.com/6x9UD))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    for (int seed = 0; seed < 4; seed++ ) {
        printf( "Seed %d:", seed);
        srand( seed );
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
            printf( "    %10d", rand() );
        printf( "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

returns

```
Seed 0:    1804289383     846930886    1681692777    1714636915    1957747793
Seed 1:    1804289383     846930886    1681692777    1714636915    1957747793
Seed 2:    1505335290    1738766719     190686788     260874575     747983061
Seed 3:    1205554746     483147985     844158168     953350440     612121425
```

Comment: Very interesting question. To my knowledge, srand does not have any "magic" value, but rand() is simply initialized to a seed of 1, and thus starts with that seed unless told something different. Which would _implicitly_ mean that if you call srand(1), you "reset to the original state". However, the output you posted suggests that it really "magically resets" to seed 0 which you had set before, not to 1 (which, btw. my implementation does _not_ do).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is probably an implementation detail. The standard mandates that the random seed 1 is special, and the internal register of your specific random generator algorithm is probably zero-initialized, thus causing the same random sequence for seed(0) and seed(1). I'd even wager that the first line of your srand() implementation looks like:

```
if ( seed == 1 ) seed = 0;
```

to force standard-conformant behaviour.

Generally, the random number generators for rand() and srand() are not required to give different sequences for different seeds, but the same sequence for the same seed. So, **don't rely on different seeds generating different random sequences**, and you should be fine. If not, welcome to implementation-specific fun.

Comment: Actually, the code is more like `if (seed == 0) seed = 1;`, since the algorithm used by the GNU implementation of `rand()` doesn't work with a seed of zero.

Comment: @MikeSeymour As I [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74193216/1778275), either way is allowed.

Answer (score 21):

How glibc does it:

> [around line 181 of glibc/stdlib/random_r.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;h=51a2e8c812aee78783bd6d38c1b6269d41c8e47e;hb=HEAD#l181), inside function `__srandom_r`
>
> ```
>   /* We must make sure the seed is not 0.  Take arbitrarily 1 in this case.  */
>   if (seed == 0)
>     seed = 1;
> ```

But that's just how glibc does it. It depends on the implementation of the C standard library.

Answer (score 7):

Neither the C nor the C++ standards say much about the specifics of the implementation of `rand()` and `srand()`.  The details are left almost entirely up to the implementor.  The C standard requires that:

> If srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.  If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1.

but it does not contain any requirement that *different* seeds must produce *different* sequences.  Apparently, on your system, seeds of zero and one have the same effect.  I would guess that this is to provide backwards compatibility with some piece of software that expects `srand(0)` to reset the PRNG to its initial state.

Answer (score 1):

*If seed is set to 1, the generator is reinitialized to its initial value and produces the same values as before any call to rand or srand.* Taken from the [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) reference

Answer (score 0):

When reading manual pages, they all state that "If no seed value is provided, the rand() function is automatically seeded with a value of 1." This is probably why the reference page you link to states that seeding with 1 resets the state.

That the same result happens for seeding with both 0 and 1 is most likely implementation dependant, and should not be counted on happening on all platforms.

Answer (score -1):

The srand() function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand(). If srand() is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand() is called before any calls to srand() are made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand() is first called with a seed value of 1.

Maybe useful: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html

Answer (score -3):

The reason 1 is specified is because some random number generators will get stuck at zero if the seed is set to zero.  For example shift-registers and Multiplicative congruential types i.e. `r(n+1) = (A * r(n))mod M`.

Many C implementations use Linear Congruential  `r(n+1) = (A * r(n) + B) mod M`, B <> 0 which don't get stuck.

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?